# DBPedia SparQL URLError: urlopen error [WinError 10060] in Python

Tags: python, sparql, dbpedia, sparqlwrapper

I am trying to run following query on dbpedia approximately 1500 times in a loop with different parameters but it gives me URLError: urlopen error [WinError 10060] error. Sometimes it gives me error after processing 15 records and sometimes it gives me error after 10 or 1,2 etc records. This error is basically thrown at random times.

```
  """
        
        SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?name ?page WHERE {{
            # VALUES ?groups {{dbo:Person dbo:Location}}
        {{
            # [Case 1] no disambiguation at all (eg. Twitter)
            ?item rdfs:label "{mention_1}"@en .
        }}
        UNION
        {{
            # [Case 1] lands in a redirect page (eg. "Google, Inc." -> "Google")
            ?temp rdfs:label "{mention_1}"@en .
            ?temp dbo:wikiPageRedirects ? ?item .   
        }}
        UNION
        {{
            # [Case 2] a dedicated disambiguation page (eg. Michael Jordan)
            <http://dbpedia.org/resource/{mention_2}_(disambiguation)> dbo:wikiPageDisambiguates ?item.
        }}
        UNION
        {{
            # [Case 3] disambiguation list within entity page (eg. New York)
            <http://dbpedia.org/resource/{mention_2}> dbo:wikiPageDisambiguates ?item .
        }}
        # Filter by entity class
        ?item rdf:type {group} .
        # Grab wikipedia link
        ?item foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?page .
        # Get name
        ?item rdfs:label ?name .
        FILTER (langMatches(lang(?name),"en"))
        # ?item rdf:type ?group .
        # ?group rdfs:label ?group_name
        # FILTER (STR(?group_name) IN ("Building", "Airport"))
    }}
    """
```

I have tried setting timeout to 1000 or 5000 but it did not fix my problem. I received this error even after setting my timeout like this. and also tried implementing retry mechanism on it but none of this worked.

```
def generate_candidates(mention, group):
    query = build_query(mention, group)
    sparql.setQuery(query)
    sparql.setTimeout(1000)
    for i in range(3):
        try:
            results = sparql.query().convert()
            return results
        except TimeoutError:
            pass
```

Comment: you should not set a timeout but some delay between the queries - I mean, you're firing 1500 queries in a short time to a public service - that is flooding a service and can lead to a temporarily being blocked request.

Comment: @UninformedUser I have tried that. I added time.sleep(5) after each query. But i still received this error.   URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>

Comment: `time.sleep(5)` is what, 5 miliseconds? Did you try a greater value? Anyways, if you have a massive workload, then loading the Dbpedia dataset into your own triple store is the only correct way. I mean, also what if DBpedia endpoint is down for a longer period of time?

Comment: @UninformedUser increasing sleep time did solve the problem. Thanks for this. I will look into triple store too